# memory leaking when using aws/s3 gem for AWS::S3::Logging::Log

Tags: ruby, memory-leaks, amazon-s3, rubygems

I have a ruby script which processes S3 logs something like this:

```
AWS::S3::Bucket.find(data_bucket).logs.each do |s3log|
  s3log.lines.each do |line|
    # accumulate stuff
  end
end
```

However, in the aws/s3 gem the :lines accessor memoizes the data.  So memory grows as I process each file.

Aside from hacking the gem, capping the files read each run, and/or running the script frequently, how can I gracefully avoid a ruby process that might grow to several gb?  Am I missing a memory management trick?

Comment: For the moment I'm going to run the job frequently, and with logs(name, :max_keys=>100), but I'm curious if there is a way to free the log files loaded into memory.  The :max_keys approach imposes a throughput limit that I need to monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The root of this is really `Bucket.objects`, which is what `Bucket.logs` uses, and which keeps references all the objects in `@object_cache`.  The caching of lines is a subsidiary problem.

Solution: I simply use two loops: the inner one fetches logs from `S3` 10 at a time, and the outer one processes until `is_truncated` is false.  This means we never keep references to more than 10 `S3` log files at a time, and my memory problem is gone.